# How do I change the colors for xterms to no color (B/W) for all Terminals on RHL in Shell and Java

Tags: java, redhat, xterm

I am trying to set all shells to B/W on a RHL systems.

I am also trying to use Java code to do the same thing for output to a terminal.

How would I accomplice this?

thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to `chmod -x /usr/bin/dircolors` which will turn off color `ls` (make sure you log out, and back in for the change to take effect). Java does not usually output ANSI color codes, so I don't think you need to do anything for that.